# Запрос к API через Nifi InvokeHttp

Tags: apache-nifi

Мне нужно сделать запрос на выгрузку json файла через API Яндекс метрики используя Nifi. API яндекс метрики работает так, что при первой отправке get запроса, сервис возвращает код 202 с сообщением, что файл добавлен в очередь на подготовку, и каждый последующий запрос с такими же атрибутами вернет либо код 200(Когда файл готов к выгрузке), либо 202, если файл еще готовится. Какой процессор я могу использовать, чтобы создать цикл который будет проверять код ответа и в случае возврата 202 делать повторный запрос, а в случае возврата 200 идти дальше?

Answer (score 0):

В Apache NiFi есть несколько процессоров, которые можно использовать для создания цикла проверки кода ответа и делать повторные запросы. Один из них - LoopBackHTTP.
Этот процессор используется для отправки HTTP запросов и обработки ответа. Вы можете использовать этот процессор в сочетании с процессором RouteOnAttribute для перенаправления потока данных в зависимости от кода ответа.
В вашем случае, вы можете создать цикл с использованием LoopBackHTTP для отправки GET запроса и RouteOnAttribute для перенаправления потока данных в зависимости от кода ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужен код на PHP для отправки GET запроса и проверки кода ответа, вы можете использовать функцию curl:

```
<?php

   $url = "https://example.com/api/endpoint";

   do {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
      $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
      $body = substr($response, $header_size);
      $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      curl_close($ch);
   } while ($status == 202);

   if ($status == 200) {
      // do something with the json data
      $json_data = json_decode($body);
      //...
   } else {
      // handle error
   }

?>
```

В этом коде, мы используем цикл do-while для отправки GET запроса и проверки кода ответа. Если код ответа равен 202, запрос будет повторяться, иначе выйдет из цикла. Если код ответа равен 200, мы можем работать с json данными, иначе обработать ошибку.

Однако, стоит иметь в виду, что ожидание ответа может быть долгим и ваш скрипт может зависнуть на этом месте. Вам может потребоваться добавить таймаут или использовать функцию sleep для добавления задержки между повторными запросами. Вы также можете использовать функцию json_last_error для проверки корректности полученных json данных.

```
<?php
$url = "https://example.com/api/endpoint";

do {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($status == 202) {
        sleep(10); // delay for 10 seconds
    }
} while ($status == 202);

if ($status == 200) {
    $json_data = json_decode($body);
    if(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        // do something with the json data
    } else {
        // handle json error
    }
} else {
    // handle error
}

?>
```

В этом коде, мы добавили функцию sleep для задержки между повторными запросами и использовали функцию json_last_error для проверки корректности полученных json данных.